# Is it possible to replace an ISDN telephone system with recent/modern hardware?

Tags: doorbell

I've often seen houses where there is the following setup:

- when somebody rings the bell at the door the telephones inside will ring
- when you pick up the phone you can talk to the person at the door
- when you call a special number on the phone (eg. *123#), the door will open
- the speaker, microphone and door opener (all 3 are at the door) are connected to an ISDN telephone system (see [this](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/T4EAAOSwBUlfd1FI/s-l1600.jpg) image)
- the telephone is also connected to the ISDN telephone system
- the ISDN telephone system has an uplink to a modern internet router so the phone can make calls to everywhere
- the ISDN telephone system is connected to the ISDN slot of the internet router

Now the ISDN telephone systems sometimes get broken and they have to be replaced. My question is if an ISDN telephone system can be replaced by modern hardware? Or am I forced to buy a used ISDN telephone system on eBay? I think there are no manufacturers still producing ISDN telephone systems.

I am living in Germany. I don't know if such a setup is common in other countries, too.

Comment: Quite a few smart door locks these days.  Just don't have a root canal on a stormy day and expect the voice control to let you in.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwPtcqcqz00

Comment: @crip659 We don't want to replace everything. We want to keep the old door bell, speaker, microphone, door opener and cables.

Comment: While you may _desire_ to keep most parts, replacing with more modern componentry may _require_ upgrading most if not all the parts involved. You can't put modern DDR4 memory in a 486 system - just not supported...

Comment: Some simple parts can probably be replaced with new parts.  I imagine parts like the door bell, door opener, microphone are just connected by wires and use a switch to use them.  The main system will probably need to be bought used if it breaks, or a new modem system installed.

Comment: has little or nothing to do with "ISDN", which is basically just a modem. What you're actually more interested in is the fancy PBX system they built on top of the PSTN/ISDN wiring. That hardware is pennies on the dollar these days, though it is drying up, so maybe buy a redundant copy of all your interface expansions, just in case.

Comment: The houses I've known in Germany, they've had fully integrated door systems where all the door stuff appears to be on its own circuit, with nothing to do with the phones. That's probably what you'd upgrade it to. Who has a phone these days?

Comment: @user253751 Only few people have their phone connected to the door system. Maybe 1 out of 10.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want local service, there are circuits that can supply the voltages needed to operate old phone instruments. I believe the Hackaday website recently featured one of these homebrews. You might need to do some adapting to make it work for non-telco equipment.

Comment: The catch is that ISDN is quite a bit more technically complex - it is digital where old POTS is analog. (Also a *lot* more capable, but those capabilities really aren't in use here on a voice-only system.)

Comment: Question is, do these devices require ISDN data, or POTS (Plain Old Telephone Service)?